# How to validate xpages with bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, xpages, lotus-notes

I have a xpages page with multiple bootstrap nav tabs on it. On submitting if some field is not validated the error is signaled, but the first field with error is not selected cause it is not on active bootstrap tab.
How can I select the tab with the failed field and then select the field?

I saw solution with dojo components, but it does not work with bootstrap.

Comment: How have you implemented bootstrap in the xpages app?

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but I built an app using the tabbed panel control (not bootstrap or dojo).  I had a lot of trouble with validation as well, and eventually gave up on the built in validation and wrote clientside javascript to handle it.  This has worked really well and I haven't had any issues and it has been in prod for a while now.

Comment: Can you write me how do you focus the invalidated field. I have fields in different tabs, and have to find out in which tab the invalidated field is in.